# What is the HWND ref that comes with HCBT_ACTIVATE when you alt-tab to the Desktop (on Win7)?

Tags: winapi, hook

I'd need to detect when the user alt-tabs to the 'Desktop' on Windows 7. The resulting HCBT_ACTIVATE message, intercepted by my global CBT hook, contains the HWND reference to a window with WorkerW set as it's class. Safe (enough) to assume there aren't many visible top level alt tab windows with WorkerW as their class? Perhaps there is a better way you'd suggest to detect that the alt-tab activated window indeed corresponds to the window switching operation that gets you to the desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing the handle to the value returned by GetDesktopWindow() could be useful.

Comment: For some reason I thought the window in question would NOT be the desktop window (I was expecting that to be a window by the name Progman?). But that does work, thanks a bunch!